# sending email using php form not working - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

I have this following `PHP` page:

```
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

  //Email information
  $admin_email = "someone@example.com";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
  $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];

  //send email
  mail($admin_email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email);

  //Email response
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }

  //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
  else  {
?>

 <form method="post">
  Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
  Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" /><br />
  Message:<br />
  <textarea name="comment" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

<?php
  }
?>
```

then I fill the form to my `@gmail.com` email, but it doesn't work ... I didn't receive anything ... why? What am I doing wrong? Is Gmail or any other email provider blocking? How can I get it to work?

Comment: first step, check the mail server log.

Comment: the `gmail` server log?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Check your spam. You could try removing the quotes in `"$subject"` but I doubt that will help any. It works with or without them. Plus, why did you tag this as `javascript`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I checked ... isn't there

Comment: sure, if you have access to gmail's server log. :-) If not your mail server will do

Comment: @Dagon I don't have a mail server ... it's just sending an email to the user

Comment: Are you running this on a local machine or hosted site?

Comment: well cant send email with out using an email server

Comment: @Fred-ii- localhost, but it will go eventually to a hosted site

Comment: As Dagon said, it won't send email without a mail server setup.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so the best thing to do is to have it forward to the user's email, using JS?

Comment: "forward to the user's email, using JS" what does that even mean ?

Comment: Only when you have `mail()` setup on your server. With or without JS, if you don't have a mail server on your machine, you're not going to go any further.